# Modify different objects without checking flags

Tags: python, oop, static-methods

I am wanting to modify different objects. At the moment I pass a flags parameter to decide whether to perform the changes or not. Is there a way to make this work without passing any flags, or is this the best way of doing it? I dont feel like this is a scalable solution once I have more instances of the objects.

```
def modifyfunc(self, flags, id_to_modify, value):
  if flags['object1']:
    self.object1.modify(id_to_modify, value)
  if flags['object2']:
    self.object2.modify(id_to_modify, value)
  if flags['object3']:
    self.object3.modify(id_to_modify, value)
```

Note that flags can be true for any `objectx`. Assume that any objectx implements the `modify` method correctly (basically, the object instances are of different types that inherit from the same base class, so they all have the method `modify` but may be implemented differently between these objects).

Comment: This needs more context. What kinds of objects are these, what are you doing with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), you can access arbitrary instance member of an object:

```
getattr(obj, instance_attribute_name)
```

Example:

```
>>> 'a'.upper()
'A'
>>> getattr('a', 'upper')()
'A'
```

---

Instead of flags, how about pass names of attribute to modify?

```
def modifyfunc(self, attr_names, id_to_modify, value):
    for attr_name in attr_names:
        getattr(self, attr_name).modify(id_to_modify, value)

...

obj.modifyfunc(['object1', 'object3'], 'id1', 'value1')
```